# React render an image dynamically after a page reload (depends on state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've a react component that I try to load image dynamically. The image is dependent on a state, that is loaded from the backend with `useEffect`. The initial state is empty.

When I change the state (using a drop list inside the form), the image is displayed correctly but when I reload the page, the image won't show up.

What I'm trying to do is to re-render / delay the render of the the component (or just  tag) after the fetch is complete. So I use `loading` as an indicator, and change it's value inside the useEffect after fetch returns.

But still when the page reloads the value of `winner` is `undefined`, and I get no image.

```js
const Winner = () => {
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState({"id": "", "name": ""})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/v1/winner`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
      setWinner(jsonData)
      setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    (loading ? <p>Loading..</p> : 
      <Box className="bonus">
        <img src={`./static/${winner.name}.png`.toLowerCase()} width="40px" height="40px" />
        <FormControl>
        ...
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
  ))
}
```

Any suggestions / help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `jsonData` after fetched ?

Comment: That's the response `{"status":"success","id":"17"}` jsonData contains

Comment: so it doesn't match with the initial state, so is the `winner.name` is `undefined` as `winner` doesn't have a prop with `name` ...

Comment: @KcH that was it. The response content didn't match what I expected as an object. I should have parsed the response first, create an object and then use setWinner.

Comment: Exactly, you can alternatively put the initial state to null and check for it as another condition before rendering .... `if(loading) return ## .. if(!winner) ## return if(winner) return ##` .... hope you got my point 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial `state` data and the data after fetch are different

> {"id": "", "name": ""}

after fetch

> {"status":"success","id":"17"}

so `winner` doesn't have a `name` prop,

Alternatively you can set the initial state to `null`

```
const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null)

....

if(loading) return "loading ..."
if(!winner) return null
if(winner) return <data.../>;
```